# Init the app when user log in/out with vue

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vue-router

Ok so i have a problem and i can’t find the answer.

So in my main.ts file i initial the vue app with fetchConfig api that includes “authenticated” property.

Whenever user logs in or out this property changes but only when i refresh the page i can get the property value.

Im looking for a solution to init the vue app on every log in or log out.

(I don't want to use fetchConfig api again after login/logout)

I tried using the “key” method on the vue-router but that didn’t help.

Thanks for your help ☺️